# Induction Enough To Ensure That Only One Solution Exists For A Functional Equation?

Tags: functions, induction, functional-equations

Suppose I have a problem involving functional equations, such as the one below ($0 \not \in \mathbb{N}$):

---

Find all functions $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ such that

- $f(n)$ is a square for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$;
- $f(m+n) = f(m) + f(n) + 2mn  \forall m,n \in \mathbb{N}$

  ---

By sheer inspection, we see that $f(n)=n^2$ might be a solution. Suppose we prove by induction that if $f(n)=n^2$ for $n=1,2,\ldots,k$, then $f(k+1)=(k+1)^2$ (it's not hard).

Does this prove that $f(n)=n^2$ is the *only* solution to the given functional equation?

Comment: Hint: does the recurrence say anything about $f (1) $?

Comment: So your induction argument only proves that if $f(1)=1$ then $f(n)=n^2$ for all $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$. Following Mark's hint, it remains to prove whether or not $f(1)$ _must_ equal 1.

Comment: Oh! That explains why the hint to the problem they find $f(n)$ in terms of $f(1)$ and *then* prove that $f(1)=1$!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all functions $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(m+n)=f(m)+f(n)+2 m n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3621484/find-all-functions-f-mathbbn-rightarrow-mathbbn-such-that-fmn-fm)