# Find all functions $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(m+n)=f(m)+f(n)+2 m n$

Tags: prime-numbers, functional-equations

> Find all functions $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that 
>   (a) $f(n)$ is a square for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ 
>   (b) $f(m+n)=f(m)+f(n)+2 m n$, for all $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$

I proved using induction that $f(n)=n\left(q^{2}+n-1\right)$ for all $n$, where $f(1)=q^2$.

The hint says that

> Thus for each prime $p$, we see that $p$ divides $q^{2}-1$. It follows that $q=1$, and this implies that $f(n)=n^{2}$.

I do not understand from where primes come into play. How do we see that each prime $p$ divides $q^{2}-1$?

Comment: @JohnOmielan No. This question is asking about a specific method, and that question and its answers do not use the method discussed here.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Also there's the added restriction here that $f(n)$ is square.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Thanks for the feedback. I've retracted my duplicate close vote, & have deleted that generated comment, but I'll leave a link to that question of [Find functions $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that $ f(m+n)=f(m)+f(n)+2mn$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2183340/602049) in this comment for anybody who is interested in checking into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With $p$ prime we have $f(p)=p(q^2+p-1)$. Since $f(p)$ is a square and $p$ divides $f(p)$, $p$ has to divide $f(p)$ *at least twice*, which means $p\mid q^2+p-1$ or $p\mid q^2-1$. Since this is true for all $p$, $q^2-1=0$, hence $q=1$.

Comment: p has to divide f(P) at least twice but why that mean p I q^2 + p - 1 or p I q^2 -1 ???

Comment: @User88463 This is Euclid's lemma. I match the first $p$ with the lone $p$, so the second $p$ has to match (divide) $q^2-p+1$.

Comment: and what about q^2 -1 ???

Comment: @User88463 I am just using basic divisibility facts here. If $p\mid n$ then $p\mid n+kp$ for any integer $k$.

Comment: yes !! thanks ....

Comment: just asking one more thing , someone here said that take $g(n)=f(n) - n^2$ and show that $g(m+n)=g(m)+g(n)$...i showed it and i get $f(n)= cn + n^2$ ....what to do now???? how to show that c=0 ??

Comment: @User88463 That was a misstep, ignore that.

Comment: ok thanks again...